# How to extend component functionality in react?

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, model-view-controller, composition

Hi I am working on some internal project I need to show case multitennacy concept in React. I have site A and B. A would have all platform components and B will inherit A components and also need to have extended functionality. For e.g A have Carousel component which has own functionality I want to introduce some new features like after first slide move I need to make any call backs etc... In React there conepts of HOC and Composition which will work for extending components as there is no inheritience concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although inheritance in react is not as widely applicable as in other frameworks (and react clearly [do not recommend](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) this approach as well), yet there is nothing that prohibits you from using inheritance when necessary:

```
export class BaseComponent extends React.PureComponent
{
    // ...
}

export class AdvancedComponent extends BaseComponent
{
    // ...
}
```

Overriding in descendants required methods.